Unable to save DS-160 application
I cannot save the application after filling in the personal details as I get an error 'The requested URL has been rejected. Please contact your administrator". I am using Google Chrome and still facing this issue. Can someone please help?
Thanks
Sandy

Are you using a device at your work or a library?
